# mysql: countaing num of columns with certain value

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I got a database contain employee name and month days in front of it

```
id         name        1    2       3     4
-----      ------      ---  --     ---    ---
1          Mark        half  full  full   half
```

i would like to count the number of columns which contain value half 
and number of columns which contain full value

like if i want to count null values i write

```
select is null(`1`)+ is null (`2`) as count from employee where id = 280
```

so what should i do or which query can solve this problem for me

Comment: Are the column names actually the integers 1, 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: This seems like a bad schema. I would recommend (id, name, date, full_or_half) instead.

Comment: and how to list all dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  (`1` = 'half') + (`2` = 'half') + (`3` = 'half') + (`4` = 'half') AS `HALF`,
        (`1` = 'full') + (`2` = 'full') + (`3` = 'full') + (`4` = 'full') AS `FULL`
FROM    TableName
-- WHERE condition here
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54169/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (use `COALESCE` if columns are nullable)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a73/2)

Comment: +1 . . . It looks right to me so it doesn't deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: yeah alot of people searching for that answer over the internet :D

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny my last comment was incorrect so I deleted It. what I mean was to create two tables with one to many relationship. On table contains the names, and the other one are the list of status per month `:D`. But you can still your current schema, it's just a suggestion anyway `:D`